# Microsoft ReportViewer Control - Method 'HandleImpersonation' in type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.DataSetExtensionConnection'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-hosting, visual-studio-lightswitch, report-viewer2012

I deployed a Ligthswitch application with microsoft reportviewer 2012. After I deployed the application to winhost I ran into this issue when I try to print any report. Everything works fine locally. I'm new to all this web development and deployment.

```
An error occurred during local report processing.
    Method 'HandleImpersonation' in type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.DataSetExtensionConnection' from assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' does not have an implementation.
```

I've been stuck on this for several days now. If anyone can help I would really appreciate it. Remember, I'm new to all this so please correct me if my wording is a bit off.

Thanks!
Aldwin M.

Comment: Have you got access to a deployment of SSRS?

Comment: No I don't have. If I did what needs to be done?

Comment: I'm guessing that the WebForms control you're using is not compatible with Lightswitch.  Lightswitch is based on MVC and could be the reason for your error.  I've been working on a Lightswitch project for the last 10 months. We've implemented SSRS and aren't using the WebForms report viewer controls.

Comment: I resolved my own issue. All I did is change the processing mode property to remote. This is part of the configuration of the report viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did is change the processing mode property of the report to remote. This is explained at msdn.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

If anyone encounters the issue let me know if you need some help.tnx!